# PhP month difference between dates in different years

Tags: php, date

I have this piece of code which is returning a weird result:

```
        $d1 = new DateTime('2018-12-01');
        $d2 = new DateTime('2009-02-03');
        $interval = $d2->diff($d1);
        echo $interval->format('%m months');
        die();
```

It's returning 9 months, which is wrong. The question is mad simple but I couldn't find an answer yet: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Carbon library it works and return 2 month

```
$d1 = new \Carbon\Carbon('2018-12-01');
$d2 = new \Carbon\Carbon('2019-02-03');
echo $d2->diffInMonths($d1);
die();
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Can't use carbon on the server, so I had to use this: https://gist.github.com/sepehr/6351322

Answer (score -1):

it works for me!

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2018-12-01');

$datetime2 = date_create('2009-02-03');

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```